# How can I split a String into a String array for each character, while grouping a "minus" sign with the integer that follows it?

Tags: java, split

Here's what I've done:

```
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String sLine = sc.nextLine();
        sLine.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        String[] scanned = sLine.split("");
```

My input is going to be something like this:

```
IF (2 -2 +) (3 2 *) (-1 4 +) (5 3 *)
```

What this means is irrelevant, but what the scanner does is store it in a string "as is", first of all.  Then I use the replaceAll function to remove all whitespace.  I am then left with:

```
IF(2-2+)(32*)(-14+)(53*)
```

I then interpret this code using java and perform the calculation if no errors occur.  My issue now is, that when I split the string into tokens, it's going to make each "minus" sign its own token, but I want to somehow relate it with the integer following it so that token is still just an integer (now negative) and have no tokens with a minus sign in it.  Is there an easy way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `negative look-behind` to split on `empty string` not preceded by a `hyphen` :-

```
str.split("(?<!-)");
```

This will not split on the empty string between `-` and `2`, thus keeping them intact.

```
String str = "IF(2-2+)(32*)(-14+)(53*)";
String[] arr = str.split("(?<!-)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

**Output: -**

```
[, I, F, (, 2, -2, +, ), (, 3, 2, *, ), (, -1, 4, +, ), (, 5, 3, *, )]
```

Now you have `-2` and `-1` instead of having `-` as separate element.

Comment: Nice! Jain can you explain what "(?<!-)" means ?

Comment: @GilPeretz.. `(?<!..)` stands for `negative look-behind`. When used as `(?<!-)"somecharacter"`, it matches a string in which `"somecharacter"` is not preceded by `-`.

Comment: @GilPeretz.. You can learn more about them here - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind

Comment: Well, I had high hopes that this was going to work, but it doesn't.  I think when it stores the tokens in the string array, it OMITS the symbols you put in the parenthesis.  So, my array does not start with a space, '(', or 'I' as anticipated using this method.

Comment: @TheRationalist.. I don't understand. Can you post your input, and expected output? And what output did you got exactly?

Comment: @RohitJain If I have an input of (5 -2 +) for example, my final String[] array needs to be (,5,-2,+,) without the commas of course.  I also understand that element[0] will probably be an empty space. I have tried to access both the 0th and 1st element to see if it was a '(', but it is not.  FYI, the array is not directly sent to output.  The array is used to check for syntax errors in a very tiny language.  (EDIT: The input has to either start with IF or a left parenths)

Comment: @TheRationalist.. If your input is: - `(5-2+)`, you will get the expected result. Note that, you would have to replace your whitespaces first.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're splitting the string up by "". What I believe you want to do is use the regular expression to split the string on how you want. If you are not familiar with Java regex, please [see this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) to familiarize yourself with it.
I suggest looking down at the Special constructs (non-capturing) section.

Hint

```
String[] scanned = sLine.split("your regex");
```

Comment: What does it mean by non-capturing?

Comment: So sorry for the late response, I was away from a computer the last few days. Anyways, a "Non-capturing" regex basically allows us to check backwards (i.e. the '-' sign) and allows us to test for multiple repetitions on a group of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong tool for this job. You need a scanner and a separate parser. The unary minus is handled by the parser, not the scanner. Have a look around for recursive descent expression parsers, Dijkstra shunting yard algorithm, etc.